# Redundant nullcheck of value known to be non-null or possible bug in findbugs

Tags: java, findbugs

Here is the code:

```
public static String readFile(InputStream is) {

        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(is); Scanner delimitedScanner = scanner.useDelimiter("\\A");) {
            return scanner.hasNext() ? scanner.next() : "";
        }
    }
```

And findbugs plugin says:

> Redundant nullcheck of value known to be non-null This method contains
>   a redundant check of a known non-null value against the constant nul

And points on this:

```
return scanner.hasNext() ? scanner.next() : "";
        } //this line contains bug!!!
    }
```

Look at the pic:

[image]

And eclipse shows the same warning:

[image]

Comment: What version of findbug do you use?

Comment: I've got 3.0.4 version in my pom.xml

Comment: but you're using findbug intergrated into your IDE. Check plugin version in Eclipse settings

Comment: And also I use finbugs maven plugin to prevent a bad code to be built. The first picture is from mvn findbugs:gui.

Comment: Ok, I've got it. What is the intent of creating `Scanner delimitedScanner = scanner.useDelimiter("\\A");` if it's not used?

Comment: I tried your example with the [Nullness Checker](https://types.cs.washington.edu/checker-framework/current/checker-framework-manual.html#nullness-checker) of the Checker Framework, and it verified the code without issuing a false positive warning as FindBugs does.

Answer (score 1):

The try-with-resources constructs confuses code analyzers and coverage tools that look directly at the byte code.  At the end of the try-with-resources block a lot of extra byte code is generated that will have the ending brace as its line number.

Apparently FindBugs seems to think there is a problem there.  However, this is almost certainly not the case.

The same thing happens with coverage tools, even though the block is fully covered, they claim that not all branches were covered.  This is because the try-with-resources block adds handling for exceptional cases or resources being null which you can't really get covered properly with for example Unit tests.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies with the JDK which rewrites try-with-resources to the form:

```
Scanner scanner = null
try {
   scanner = new Scanner(is);
} finally {
  if (null != scanner) {try {scanner.close();} catch (Exception e) {...}}
}
```

Seems like this should already be fixed, so please check your findbugs plugin version.
(https://sourceforge.net/p/findbugs/bugs/1169/)